# How to use a newly defined column name in the where clause of a query in sql 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in sql server 2008 like:

```
select t1.Id, 
MatchIds = (select dbo.GetCommaDelimitedString(t2.Id) from #temp t2
       where t1.Id != t2.Id and t1.PatientId=t2.PatientId 
       and t1.HCN=t2.HCN 
      )
from #temp t1
```

This query has an output like:

```
Id   MatchIds
1    2,5,6
2    1,5,6
3    null
4    null
5    1,2,6
6    1,2,5
```

What I want is to get rid of the rows whose MatchIds is null. When I try to add `MatchIds is not null` with a where clause to the main query, it is not accepting it saying that `invalid column name MatchIds`and I do not want to write the same query I used to assign MatchIds in the where clause as well. In this case, what is the best way to provide it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move query to `CROSS APPLY`

```
select t1.Id, 
       cs.MatchIds
from #temp t1
CROSS APPLY (select dbo.GetCommaDelimitedString(t2.Id) from #temp t2
       where t1.Id != t2.Id and t1.PatientId=t2.PatientId 
       and t1.HCN=t2.HCN) cs (MatchIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (select t1.Id, 
MatchIds = (select dbo.GetCommaDelimitedString(t2.Id) from #temp t2
       where t1.Id != t2.Id and t1.PatientId=t2.PatientId 
       and t1.HCN=t2.HCN 
      )
from #temp t1) results
WHERE results.MatchIds IS NOT NULL;
```

Use your result as a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

A CTE can also work:

```
WITH CTE_matches AS
(
select t1.Id, 
MatchIds = (select dbo.GetCommaDelimitedString(t2.Id) from #temp t2
   where t1.Id != t2.Id and t1.PatientId=t2.PatientId 
   and t1.HCN=t2.HCN)
from #temp t1
)

SELECT Id, MatchIds FROM CTE_matches WHERE MatchIds IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: * `IS NOT NULL`